# Where to download US zipcode polygons?

Tags: data, web-mapping, zip-codes

I need US zipcode areas (polygons) for a web map implementation. Can you tell me where to find it (free or paid)?

Comment: [ZIP Codes aren't polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13114578/1048862)

Comment: Ok, where I can find any zipcode data?